# Ubuntu 16.04 - Mount S3 volume in Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ubuntu-16.04, systemd, s3ql

I am attempting to get a AWS S3 volume to mount on boot using systemd on Ubuntu 16.04, utilizing S3QL.   As of now, I can successfully mount the volume manually using mount.s3ql.

I have also created a systemd serverice (s3ql.service) and running the following will mount the volume:

```
$ sudo systemctl start s3ql
```

After a reboot I get

```
$ systemctl status s3ql.service 
3ql.service - mount s3ql filesystem
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/s3ql.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

So to me that looks like the service is loaded, but has 'completed' and stopped. The volume does not mount. The contents of /etc/systemd/system/s3ql.service

```
[Unit]
Description=mount s3ql filesystem
Wants=network-online.target


[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mount.s3ql --fg --cachedir /var/cache/s3ql --authfile /root/.s3ql/authinfo2 --compress none --cachesize 1048576 --allow-other s3://My-Bucket /mnt/My-MountPoint
ExecStop=/usr/bin/umount.s3ql /mnt/plx-mnda
TimeoutStopSec=42
```

My assumption is there is something wrong in that syntax.

Cheers 
JJ

Comment: Well, I was able to resolve this myself.  I realized that my s3ql.service was in the /etc/systemd/system/ folder.  This marked the service as static and that is should have been in a target.wants folder.  I created a syslink (although I assume I should just re-create the service file)  `sudo ln -s /etc/systemd/system/s3ql.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/s3ql.service`